# How to refer to a variable dynamically

Tags: php

So I'm trying to compare 2 variables however one of them I'm not sure how to create.

I have a bunch of variables set like $price1, $price2 etc. etc.

Now depending on what is being posted, I want to compare $paid to $price(pricenumber)

How exactly would I grab the pricenumber being posted and add it behind $price in the variable comparison?

Comment: `$number = 2; echo ${"price" . $number};`, but I would not suggest to do so - use associative arrays, do not create a mess with huge number of variables.

Comment: so assuming I have already set $number would this work?    if($p->ipn_data["mc_gross"] == echo ${"price" .$number};)

Comment: No, with `echo` it would not work, because I used it just to show an output. `if ($p->ipn_data["mc_gross"] == ${"price" .$number})`. But, again, this is wrong, do not do it.

Comment: how exactly is it wrong?

Comment: I wrote it in the first comment. If you have this kind of data - store it in array. Do not create huge number of the same variables `$price1`, `$price2` and so on. For a couple of variables it is ok, but for a large numbers - not good. The more lookalike variables you have - it is easier to make a mistake and overwrite the value. Or what would happen if you want to pass all values as argument of the function?